# "Indicate how long you plan to stay" in Canada visa?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, canada

Say I need to travel to Canada within a week. Generally, visa processing takes one month(for Indians). Although the first travel date is in the next week, I will also have requirement to travel multiple times in the following months.

Now my concern is that whether or not I miss the next week, I still have to go in the next month most probably.

So if I give the From date as next week, will the visa officer reject my application? as I can't get the visa by next week? Does it work like that?

1. I apply today
2. By the time the visa officer processes it, the From date already passed
3. What's the decision of visa officer?

If I get the rejection after long delay like a month, I will have to again apply in which case I may also miss the next month's plan.

**Edit:**

Requirement: Multiple Entry Business Visitor

The field states "how long you plan to stay" but the required answer fields are in the form of "From" and "To" dates.

Origin country: India

Thanks

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to match your question. When they ask how long you plan to stay, you should tell them how long you plan to stay. That's not affected by whether you have subsequent trips or not. Anybody who answers will also need to know your citizenship (I assume India, based on the tag, but you don't state this clearly) and the reason for travel (I *guess* these are likely to be business trips rather than tourism if you need to travel so regularly, but your question doesn't make this clear)

Comment: @ChrisH Thank you. I will edit my question. To be clear, although the field asks "how long you plan to stay" the answers fields are in the form of "from date" to "to date".

Comment: @ChrisH I edited my question.

Comment: I don't have the knowledge to answer this myself, but your edits will make it easier for those who are familiar with Canadian visa applications & processing to give you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The visa officer will adjudicate the application and its merits **at the time** they receive it. The VFS does not have the mandate to adjudicate applications, they only review it for completion.

Thus it depends on the time the visa officer receives it, not the submission time. When it is received after the event for which you planned to visit has passed, it is supposed to be rejected because it fails the trip purpose consideration. Refer to the **Operational instructions and Guidelines** for Canadian visa officers.

[Temporary residents: Eligibility and admissibility considerations](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/temporary-residents/visitors/eligibility-admissibility-considerations.html)

> 1. What is the purpose of your trip?
>
> Things to consider:
>
> - What will the person be doing in Canada?

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.